# What is the alternative to QWebInspector in Qt WebEngine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, web-inspector, qwebengineview

The example of the code snippet is here:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebChannel
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings

class AppWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.view = WebView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True);
        self.page = self.view.page()
        self.page.setDevToolsPage(self.page)

        #self.inspector = QWebInspector(self) # Crash is here!!!
        #self.inspector.setPage(self.page)
        #self.inspector.hide()
```

The three lines above were working perfectly in previous versions.

What is the alternative to `QWebInspector` in PySide2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no equivalent `QWebInspector` class for QWebEngine, because the dev tools are provided by the underlying Chrome browser. An environment variable needs to be set to enable the tools, and you can then access them via a separate Chrome-based browser - see [Qt WebEngine Developer Tools](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-debugging.html#qt-webengine-developer-tools) in the Qt5 docs for the full details.

Below is a simple demo based on your example code:

[image]

```
import sys, os

DEBUG_PORT = '5588'
DEBUG_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:%s' % DEBUG_PORT
os.environ['QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING'] = DEBUG_PORT

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebChannel
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings

class AppWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.view = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)

        self.view.loadFinished.connect(self.handleLoaded)
        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://google.com/'))

        self.inspector = QWebEngineView()
        self.inspector.setWindowTitle('Web Inspector')
        self.inspector.load(QtCore.QUrl(DEBUG_URL))

    def handleLoaded(self, ok):
        if ok:
            self.view.page().setDevToolsPage(self.inspector.page())
            self.inspector.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = AppWindow()
win.setGeometry(600, 100, 600, 480)
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: (1) How to dock the DevToolsPage to the bottom of current page? (2) It is strange that why the doc don't guide us use the `setDevToolsPage` to help show it ? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebengine-debugging.html#qt-webengine-developer-tools

Comment: @iMath The inspector is just a normal widget, so you can use it however you like. It doesn't have to be a separate window.