# QtWebEngine: DevToolsActivePort file is missing

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, chromium

When using the QtWebEngine, you can enable the chromium debug dev tools with setting the `QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING` environment variable. Normally Chromium creates a `DevToolsActivePort` file, which contains the information about the debug port. However when using the QtWebEngine, this file is not created. How can I make Qt/Chromium create this file?

Comment: Why do you want the file?

Comment: To get the debug port and websocket address.

Comment: Set the port to whatever you like. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892608/984421).

Comment: The tricky part is the websocket address since it contains a GUID. While I found a workaround ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72925493/4028761)), the general question still stands.

Comment: What evidence do you have that chromium "normally" creates this file? The relevant part of the source code noted in your other question suggests this is *not* the case: it's only written if the `output_directory` is set, which comes from a command-line argument specific to Torque; there's no default if the option isn't set. But in any case, you still haven't given a valid reason why you would need this file, since the information can already be obtained by other means.

Comment: Evidence: The bunch of other `DevToolsActivePort` files existing on my machine, created by other applications using Chromium under the hood. Also when creating a Chromium instance with Selenium for example, this file also is created.

Reason: This is unexpected behaviour. Also see here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/content/browser/devtools/devtools_http_handler.cc#284

Comment: To repeat: the source shows the file is only created if `output_directory` is set. I really don't see the point of this question. If you think you've found a bug, report it on the [Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa).